# Color blur when generating lighting[Unity]

Tags: unity-game-engine

Good day. There was a problem, when baking light, a red blur occurs. With what it can be connected? I would be glad for any help.

[image]

[image]

P.s. I am using LWRP

Answer (score 0):

Changing the Feature set to "Post Processing v2" helped
[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/NhX7d.png)